# Derivation of an identity for matrix inversion

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a machine learning textbook by Bishop, in appendix, it shows an identity as follows

$(P^{-1} + B^T R^{-1}B)^{-1}B^T R^{-1} = PB^T(BPB^T + R)^{-1}$

I would like to know if this identity has a specific name in mathematics and how to prove it by derivation ? Since I cannot find it my linear algebra textbooks.

Comment: I don't know if this form has a name, but it's a relative of the Woodbury formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity

Comment: I agree with @fqq All identities like that are more or less connected to Schur's complement.

Answer (score 2):

We have $B^\top R^{-1} (BPB^\top+R) = B^\top R^{-1}BP B^{\top} + B^\top = (P^{-1}+B^\top R^{-1}B)PB^\top$ by distributivity.

Left multiplication with $(P^{-1}+B^\top R^{-1}B)^{-1}$ and right multiplication with $(BPB^\top+R)^{-1}$ results in your identity.

I don't know of any name for this identity, and I haven't seen it until today.